# PHP $_SESSION can it hold large files?

Tags: php, post, session-variables

I'm building a multi-page form with PHP. I'm storing most of the value's in $_SESSION. Using the following method...

```
$_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['title'];
```

It's working fine so far but I'm not sure if it will be able to hold PDFs, videos, ect.

Does the $_SESSION only hold strings & intigers, or can files be stored there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Store Images in SESSION data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754145/php-store-images-in-session-data)

Comment: the session values are stored in a file, so I don't think it can store and end of file byte

Comment: can vs. should is very appropriate here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum size of a $_SESSION is the maximum memory allowed to a PHP script, but chances are  if you even get to 1/3 of that, you're doing something wrong.

`$_SESSION`, as a rule, should only be used to keep what information is needed by the user for the majority of the site page views. It is *highly* improbable, that you will actually need a file on each page.

Here's a better option, store a temp file on the disk and assign the path to the temp file in the `$_SESSION`. Then, when you need it, read the file to the user.

Comment: I'm reading that the tmpfile() is automatically removed at the end of the php script? Wouldn't that make it not possible for use with a 'multi-page' form?

Comment: Create a file named by the `PHPSESSID` and have a cron job clean them up after a given interval.

Answer (score 5):

I do not suggest you to store big value because this information is stored in your server. You should serialize a PHP object that will contain path to those file if you want to keep some reference to these files.

Edit:
The session is loaded into memory at run time, so in theory it's limited by the `memory_limit` in php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you would be able to store an entire file into $_SESSION, but you could upload your file to the server and store only a path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

By default the sessions are stored as files on the server. The only limit opposed is the PHP script memory limit - eg 64MB, which can be controlled. Files can be stored in both binary and text format but I would question the need to do so - after all, why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` is stored on server in the folder where it defined in the php.ini

so as long as your server has space you can store anything on the `$_SESSION`