# Dealing with image upload on server

Tags: php, image, session

I have got a the following problem: I have got multi-step form where in one step user upload image to server and then few steps further supplies other information, when this information is invalid no data should be commited - also the image should be deleted.

I was thinking about PHP session, but I've read here [PHP - Store Images in SESSION data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754145/php-store-images-in-session-data) that it is inefficient way. Every time you proceed step in the form the image is reloaded (in the session) and as somebody mentioned "You will want it to only be as big as it needs to be and you need to delete it as soon as you don't need it because large pieces of information in the session will slow down the session startup." - here i got a question: will it slow down the stratup the session of user who upload file or sessions of all users?

I have to mention that I'm looking for solution that doesn't rely on operating system scripts (cron or etc) - I have no permission to run such scripts.

The perfect solution for me would be: saving image on disk (for example in some folder named after session id) then after the latest step of form move this image or delete depending on form validation. If user unexpectedly destroy the session (for example closing the browser) of course the folder with image should be deleted. In nutshell I need somethig like callback to event "destroying session".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to save the image in on the disk in a temporary location. You can then store the filename of the file in the user's session.

Regarding cleaning up orphaned sessions, you can write your own session save handler and set it using [session_set_save_handler().](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

Effectively, you will need to write your own handlers for opening, saving, reading, writing, destroying and garbage collecting sessions.

In your case, you would have an extra bit of code in the destroying and garbage collecting that also removes unwanted images connected to that session.

Here's a [pretty good blog post](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database) about writing your own custom session handler. The example uses MySQL as the storage backend, but you should be able to adapt it to your storage handler of choice.

Comment: I am not so experienced with PHP Sessions. I see I probably need to write my own callback for $destroy. The question is: will it overwrite the default behaviour or just my callback will be run after default actions. I prefer the latter because I don't know what exactly happens when PHP destroys user session so I don't want to screw something up...

Comment: I don't think there's anyway to selectively use the default behaviour of sessions. However, if you are using standard file based sessions, then you just simply have to delete the appropriate session file for the user.

Comment: If you can use PHP 5.4, you can extend SessionHandler and modify its behaviour to your needs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php

Answer (score 0):

I think phpdev's idea of storing the file into a temporary location on disk and recording the location in `$_SESSION` but I'd go with a far simpler "garbage" (or rather unwanted image) collection routine.

I'd tie the cleanup routine to some user triggered event (your choice of either an image upload, a successful copy of the image out of the temporary dir, etc) and just have that cleanup routine `glob()` or `opendir()` the temporary dir for all files and delete any older than some pre-determined value.

That way you can run with session handling in "out of the box" config and not have to worry about any custom session handlers.